# replace() method in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, methods, replace

'Hello World!'.toUpperCase().replace('Hello', 'GOODBYE').substring(0, 7);
'HELLO W'

Hi, the first line above is what i type and the 2nd line is the output. It seems to ignore the 'replace' method and does not give an error message on Chrome browser 'Developer tools'.

Below is an 'Issue':
A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.
1 source
2.90afa11d.chunk.js:1
Learn more: User-Agent String Reduction

I tried:
'Hello World!'.toUpperCase().replace('Hello', 'GOODBYE').substring(0, 7);

and expected:
'GOODBYE'

but instead got this:
'HELLO W'

Comment: `'Hello World!'.toUpperCase().replace('HELLO', 'GOODBYE');` it is case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Hello World!'.toUpperCase().replace('Hello', 'GOODBYE');
```

`toUpperCase()` method changed "Hello World!" to "HELLO WORLD!"
Now when `replace()` method is trying to find Hello in the given string "HELLO WORLD" it is unable to find

To fix this you can either remove `.toUpperCase()` or write HELLO instead of Hello in `.replace()` method depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
'Hello World!'.toUpperCase().replace('Hello'.toUpperCase(), 'GOODBYE').substring(0, 7);
```